# Why list of object is null in query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'am trying to get list of object from query parameter but it's null.

I Added `[FromQuery]` before it but it's still null

Controller :

```
[HttpGet("filter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredSperms([FromQuery] List<SpermFilterDTO> filters, [FromQuery] string name)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetSpermsByFilterQuery { Filters = filters });

        foreach (var item in filters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Index is {item.Index}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Name is {name}");

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

name property is Ok but filters is empty.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the query string sent?

Comment: I used swagger to sent request and it's generated this messed up query string : 

https://localhost:7280/api/Sperm/filter?filters=%7B%0A%20%20%22index%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22min%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22max%22%3A%200%0A%7D&filters=%7B%0A%20%20%22index%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22min%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22max%22%3A%200%0A%7D&filters=%7B%0A%20%20%22index%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22min%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22max%22%3A%200%0A%7D&filters=%7B%0A%20%20%22index%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22min%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22max%22%3A%200%0A%7D&name=test'

Comment: I would not recommend transmitting complex objects via query string. It is acceptable to have a GET request with a body.

Comment: There is no official OpenAPI Spec support for deeply-nested objects (as arrays or lists) in query strings, so, as @AndrewH says, the better aproach is GETting them in the body of the request

Comment: Thanks, I Changed the method to post and get filters from body of request and everything is fine ...

Comment: @Pablo consider posting your solution as an answer to the question.

Comment: @J.Salas yes there is. https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#style-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended (nor really supported) to place complex objects in the query string. A GET action supports a request body and a GET request with a body is not forbidden by any specification or standard.

Thus, moving the object from the query to the body will allow your action to function as intended.

```cs
...
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredSperms([FromBody] List<SpermFilterDTO> filters, [FromQuery] string name)
...
```

Comment: Please explain, in my C# projects a GET request cannot have a body... It will throw an error like: "TypeError: Window.fetch: HEAD or GET Request cannot have a body."

Comment: @M1sterPl0w keep in mind comments are not the place to ask questions but discuss an answer. The error you're describing sounds more like a limitation of JavaScript than C#. There are plenty of discussions about why or why not a GET request can/should allow a request body.